# ionic 2 virtual scroll not working

Tags: ionic2, scrollview, infinite-scroll

I have some cards that repeat using *ngFor. It works perfectly, however the array I pass to ngFor will have an amount that varies unpredictably, it could be a small number it could be big. I want to implement virtual scroll incase the number is large.

The [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/) examples show virtual scroll used with a list.

I don't see the need for a list tag in my code, but the way I've done it doesn't seem to be right for virtualScroll because the page won't render at all in the simulator. It's completely blank. Everything was fine before I added virtualScroll.

My Code:

```
<ion-card id="card" [virtualScroll]="listOfEvents" >

      <ion-item *virtualItem="let event"]>



        <ion-row>
            <ion-col><span class="showDetails">Date:</span>{{getFormattedTime(event.eventTime, 'MM-dd-yyyy')}}</ion-col><ion-col><span class="showDetails">Time:</span>{{getFormattedTime(event.eventTime, 'HH:MM')}}</ion-col><ion-col><span class="showDetails">Venue:</span> {{event.venue}}</ion-col>   <!-- convert time to normal time-->
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col><span class="showDetails">Guests Needed:</span> {{event.guests}} </ion-col><ion-col><span class="showDetails">Cover:</span> {{event.coverCharge}}</ion-col><ion-col><span class="showDetails">Drink Min:</span>{{event.drinkMin}} </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col><span class="showDetails">Will Reimburse:</span> {{event.reimburse}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <button id="volunteer" ion-button block> volunteer </button>


       </ion-item>


    </ion-card>



</ion-content>
```

Comment: Use https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ and check the logs

Comment: <ion-item *virtualItem="let event"]> hav eyou missed '[' in this line of code?